# incorrect redux actions dispatched

Tags: redux, react-redux

I am new to redux, and working on an application. My sign-in and sign-up functionalities are working almost fine, except the fact that if some incorrect actions are being dispatched and not able to locate which part of the code is doing it. Below I am posting some code snippets.

Look at the second ghost LOGIN_FULFILLED Request, it should not occur as I don't have that user in the DB yet!
[Screenshot for the actions and state transitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OdO4L.png)

Login action creators:

```
import request from 'axios';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import store from '../store'

export function loginFunc(username, password) {  
return {
type: 'LOGIN',
username,
password,    
payload : request
            .post("http://localhost:5000/users/authenticate", 
                { 
                  username : username, 
                  password: password 
                }
            )
            .then(function (response) {
              console.log(response);
              if (response.data.message === "user_found")                    
                store.dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_FULFILLED', payload : response.data.results});
              else 
                store.dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED', payload : "user_not_found"});
            })
            .catch(function (error) {
              console.log(error);
              store.dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED', payload : error});
            })
  }
}
```

Comment: Hey. There are 2 actions dispatched: `LOGIN_REJECTED` and `LOGIN_FULFILLED` in the screenshot you shared There should be only one action dispatched right?

Comment: But it is in if - else loop so it should fire either of those based upon response message from the server.

Comment: Are you using redux-thunk? I guess not. Can you post the complete action creator function?

Comment: Yes I am using redux-thunk, I updated the code snippet in the Q.

Comment: If you are using redux-thunk, it should return a callback.

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that, can you post a related link?

Comment: `const INCREMENT_COUNTER = 'INCREMENT_COUNTER';

function increment() {
  return {
    type: INCREMENT_COUNTER
  };
}

function incrementAsync() {
  return dispatch => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      // Yay! Can invoke sync or async actions with dispatch
      dispatch(increment());
    }, 1000);
  };
}
`
This is an example of action creator.
or check this link https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk

Comment: Something similar to that works, I think I need to spend some more time on redux basics.

Comment: Yes. I will write an answer for you to understand better.

Comment: export function loginFunc(username, password) {  
  return (dispatch) => {
    return request
       <async-call>
           .then(function (response) {                                       
                  if ()  {
                      dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_FULFILLED', p});
                    }
                  else{
                      dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED', p});
                  }                     
                })
                .catch(function (error) {
                  store.dispatch({type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED, p});
                })
    }
    }

Comment: That's correct. Let me know if you have any other issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Redux Thunk middleware allows you to write action creators that return a function instead of an action (as written in [official guide](https://github.com/gaearon/redux-thunk)).

You need to make few changes to make use of thunk. You need not import `store` to use `getState` and `dispatch` as they are **arguments** to the `callback`.

```
return function(dispatch, getState)
```

This `dispatch`, `getState` is same as `store.dispatch` and `store.getState`.

```js
import request from 'axios';

export function loginFunc(username, password) {
  return function(dispatch) {
    request
      .post("http://localhost:5000/users/authenticate", {
        username: username,
        password: password
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if (response.data.message === "user_found")
          dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_FULFILLED',
            payload: response.data.results
          });
        else
          dispatch({
            type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED',
            payload: "user_not_found"
          });
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
        dispatch({
          type: 'LOGIN_REJECTED',
          payload: error
        });
      })
  }
}
```